# Javascript: skip multiple levels in multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, lodash

I have an array, holding a flat list of objects, one and each of them with a parent property, an id and a few other things. I can use that to build up a tree structure. What I would like to do is to actually just receive the items that are on a certain level:

```
   1
      1.1
          1.1.1
      1.2      
          1.2.1
              1.2.1.1
```

Like, if `arr` is my original array, I could do `unflatten(arr)` to make it a tree-like structure, and from there skip level 1 and 2, leaving the objects 1.1.1, 1.2.1 and 1.2.1.1 in a (flat) array of objects.

This is what I have right now, building up a tree-structure with lodash:

http://plnkr.co/edit/eRvVegJsZ9JPYeJCVwOc?p=preview

Not sure if I even need to go through the "unflatten" function, in order to get what I want, but that is what I thought I might need, seems easier to "cut" level 1 & 2 from there. My goal is to use a function, where I provide the array and the number of levels to skip.

Comment: Hello! It would be clearer to have an example before/after.

Comment: The array I have in the plnkr.co link, I'd like to make ot something like this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just want to have all elements from levels `>=k` in a list?

Then following code probably will help you

```
function findId(arr, id) {
  return _.findIndex(arr, function(el) {
    return el.id == id;
  });
}

function depth(arr, idx) {
  if (arr[idx] && arr[idx].parent) {
    var parentId = arr[idx].parent;
    var parentIdx = findId(arr, parentId);
    return depth(arr, parentIdx) + 1;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}

function unflattenFromLevel(arr, minLevel) {
  return _.filter(arr, function(el) {
    var idx = findId(arr, el.id);
    return depth(arr, idx) >= minLevel;
  });
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cqqc09ox/2/) is the code with some test in jsFiddle.

Or if you do not care about readability but only about slimness

```
function depth(arr, idx) {
  if (arr[idx] && arr[idx].parent) {
    return depth(arr, _.findIndex(arr, el => el.id == arr[idx].parent)) + 1;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}

function unflattenFromLevel(arr, minLevel) {
  return _.filter(arr, el => depth(arr, _.findIndex(arr, el2 => el2.id == el.id)) >= minLevel);
}
```

[Here it is](https://jsfiddle.net/cqqc09ox/3/)

However I have to warn you that this code has asymptotic of `O(n^3)`, which means you should not use it when `n` becomes greater than 100. It can be optimized to a linear solution.

Comment: Pitchperfekt, thanks a lot! And whoa, that's be more than enough with n > 100 ;), I need this for an array of 10-20 items. Any idea if this can be slimmed somewhat using lodash?

Comment: Impressive, indeed. Very well done - thanks, works just like I wished it would.

Comment: There is a special action for such cases. You may accept the answer ;)